# problema al ejecutar código Python

Tags: python

Tengo un pequeño problema y es el siguiente: En este caso, tengo que convertir la TUPLA con nombre `date` a una STRING

```
#main.py ESTE ARCHIVO NO SE PUEDE MODIFICAR
import dates

day = "01"
month = "06"
year = "1970"
date = (day, month, year)

result = dates.datetuple2datestr(date)
print(result)
```

```
#dates.py ESTE ARCHIVO SI SE PUEDE MODIFICAR
def datetuple2datestr(date):
    from main import day
    from main import month
    from main import year
    result = date   
    result = (day+"-"+month+"-"+year)
    return result
```

A la hora de ejecutar el código se muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
01-06-1970
01-06-1970
```

Necesito que se imprima una única vez.

Comment: tenes dos results quita uno de ellos y listo

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que tu código está evaluando dos veces el módulo `main`:

- Cuando ejecutas el Script
- Cuando `datetuple2datestr`()`hace`from main import day`

Y como el módulo `main` tiene un `print`, el resultado se imprime dos veces. Conceptualmente es algo así:

```
variable = "Asignada al comienzo del main"
def funcion():
    from main import variable
    return variable

print(funcion())

Asignada al comienzo del main
Asignada al comienzo del main
```

Acá es dónde es útil usar :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(funcion())
```

Este código, logra que el `print(funcion())` o cualquier código que agregues en el bloque del `if`, se evalúe únicamente en la instancia de ejecución del script y no por ejemplo en un `import`.

Comment: Muchisímas gracias por su ayuda. Me has ayudado muchísimo y de paso me ha servido para recordar este método

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente de la respuesta de Patricio que ya te soluciona el problema, no necesitas volver a importar `day`, `month` y `year` en tu archivo `dates.py` puesto que le estás pasando una tupla que ya los contiene a la función `datetuple2datestr()`.

Simplemente con poner lo siguiente en `dates.py` ya te devolvería la fecha:

```
def datetuple2datestr(date):
    return '-'.join(date)
```